# <f:ajax> Unable to attach <f:ajax> to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I receive the following error when running my application:

```
<f:ajax> Unable to attach <f:ajax> to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent
```

My JSF:

```
    <h:commandButton id="submitschool" action="submit" value="Get templates" style="FONT-SIZE: medium;FONT-FAMILY: 'Rockwell';width : 128px; height : 24px;">
    <ui:repeat value="#{person.theImage}" var="item">
    <f:ajax event="change" render="image" />
    <h:graphicImage id="image" value="#{item}"/>
    </ui:repeat>
    </h:commandButton>
```

I'm trying to return back elements in an array to the view, where "theImage" is an array in person class.

Answer (score 17):

The [`<f:ajax>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) tag can only be directly nested in an [`UIComponent`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) which implements the [`ClientBehaviorHolder`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/behavior/ClientBehaviorHolder.html) interface. The [`<ui:repeat>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html) isn't one of them.

Click the javadoc link, it tells the following:

> #### All Known Implementing Classes:
>
> HtmlBody, HtmlCommandButton, HtmlCommandLink, HtmlDataTable, HtmlForm, HtmlGraphicImage, HtmlInputSecret, HtmlInputText, HtmlInputTextarea, HtmlOutcomeTargetButton, HtmlOutcomeTargetLink, HtmlOutputLabel, HtmlOutputLink, HtmlPanelGrid, HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox, HtmlSelectManyCheckbox, HtmlSelectManyListbox, HtmlSelectManyMenu, HtmlSelectOneListbox, HtmlSelectOneMenu, HtmlSelectOneRadio

It's not clear from your question what your intent is, so I can't give a more specific answer than recommending to get rid of the `<f:ajax>` in this context. It doesn't belong there. Maybe you meant to put it directly inside the [`<h:commandButton>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html) (which is of type [`HtmlCommandButton`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlCommandButton.html)), but then you need to change the `change` event since it wouldn't make sense on a `<input type="submit">` generated by the `<h:commandButton>`.

I think you would also like to move the `<ui:repeat>` out of the `<h:commandButton>` since that does also not make much sense. Put it next to the `<h:commandButton>` instead of nesting inside it.

Comment: Hello again BalusC. I think it would be clearer if I showed you my code. I'll be posting another question...

-C

Comment: Link to new post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542144/returning-multiple-images-to-jsf-page