# JSF and p:ajax inside p:dataTable inside ui:repeat

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine, jsf, primefaces

I'm familiar with RichFaces, but relatively new to Primefaces and trying to implement a simple `h:graphicImage` inside a `p:dataTable` (additionally inside a `ui:repeat`). This is the subsequent question of [p:ajax inside h:graphicImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307407).

I will split the following `xhtml`-code to directly comment the behavior:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
      xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <h:head id="head">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
  </h:head>
    <h:body id="body">
      <f:view contentType="text/html">
```

Now the first `h:form` follows which contains a `h:outputText` and a `h:graphicImage`. By clicking on the image the bean method is called and the *counter* is correctly updated.

```
<h:form id="f1">
  <h:outputText id="counter" value="#{clientBean.counter}" />
  <h:graphicImage url="/images/circle-ok.png">
    <p:ajax event="click" update="counter" process="@this"
            listener="#{clientBean.tag}"/>
  </h:graphicImage> 
</h:form><hr/>
```

In the second `h:form` the button is inside a `p:dataTable`. If I click on the image, the bean method is called the counter is updated. (**Note** At firt I've tried to `update="counter"` without success)

```
<h:form id="f2">
  <p:dataTable var="var" value="#{clientBean.vf}">
    <p:column> 
      <f:facet name="header">Tag</f:facet>
      <h:graphicImage url="/images/circle-ok.png">
        <p:ajax event="click" update="f1:counter" process="@this"
                listener="#{clientBean.tag}" />
      </h:graphicImage>
    </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
</h:form><hr/>
```

The image inside `ui:repeated` updates the *counter* as expected:

```
<ui:repeat var="var1" value="#{clientBean.list}">   
  <h:form id="f3">
    <h:graphicImage url="/images/circle-ok.png">
  <p:ajax event="click" update="f1:counter" process="@this"
              listener="#{clientBean.tag}" />
    </h:graphicImage>
```

Now lets come to the `p:dataTable` inside a `ui:repeat`. With this piece of code the bean method is **not** called:

```
    <p:dataTable var="var2" value="#{var1.list}">
      <p:column>  
        <f:facet name="header">Tag</f:facet>
        <h:graphicImage url="/images/circle-ok.png">
         <p:ajax event="click" update="f1:counter" process="@this"
                 listener="#{clientBean.tag}" />
        </h:graphicImage> 
      </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
   </h:form>
 </ui:repeat>
</f:view></h:body></html>
```

In this case I get the `<partial-response><changes><update id="f1:counter">...`, but the bean method is not called (an inside it's `tag()`method the *counter* not updated). This is tested with a debug.
I've read 
[unable to use <p:ajax> on my primeface's datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856367/unable-to-use-pajax-on-my-primefaces-datatable)
but I have the same behaivour with `primefaces-3.0.M3.jar` and `primefaces-2.2.1.jar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to have a similar issue. I might be paranoid but my impression is the iterative component `UIData` and `UIRepeat` in JSF2 are bugged. In particular they won't handle component state properly when they are nested. I have patched `UIRepeat` myself and it works for me with any level of nesting. I know iterative component from tomahawk works correctly as well.

In your particular case a reasonably simple workaround could help since you want the same behavior regardless of which image is clicked. Create a `h:commandLink` say in form f1 with proper ajax element inside and id like 'update-counter'. Hide it. Add onclick attribute to your graphicImage with value `jsf.ajax.request("f1:update-counter", event, {render: "f1:counter", execute="@this"})`. You may need to replace the first argument with `document.getElementById("f1:update-counter")`, I'm not sure. This javascript api call should be equivalent to clicking the hidden commandLink. Alternatively you may try to skip the commandLink and pass graphicImage id/DOM node from f1 instead.

I used to do this with `f:ajax`, but maybe will work for `p:ajax` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of the workaround. In reality I don't want the same behavior, I have only described it in this way to demonstrate the problem with a _simple_ example. But does the impression of a buggy JSF2 handling the component state why the bean is not called?

Comment: The state saving problem was related to UIData/UIRepeat not cleaning up client ids after processing. This resulted in states being saved under keys with iteration indexes and they won't match with restored component ids. As a consequence state of the nested iterator is lost. Here is another solution for you: use c:forEach instead of surrounding ui:repeat so no iterating components are nested.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's good to use JSTL tags in JSF, the web is full of contrivers discussions. Although it's working with `c:foreach` I have the side effect that for each AJAX request the `@PostConstruct` method of my `@ViewScoped` bean is called resulting in really poor performance.

Comment: I sometimes use c:forEach in JSF. The difference is it will create a separate set of components in each iteration since it's a tag handler, not a component. Also the ids assigned to components under c:forEach are overridden with automatic ones.

Comment: I'm tending to share your opinion that nested iterative components may be buggy ... :-(