# Ajax close listener for p:confirmDialog

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a confirmDialog and I need to do some action when the dialog is canceled. I've attached that action to 'close' button, but I need to do that also when user click 'x' icon in the top corner. How to do that?

I've tried ajax listener:

```
<p:confirmDialog appendToBody="true">
    <p:ajax event="close" onstart="myAction()"/> 
</p:confirmDialog>
```

but I've got an error:

> Unable to attach  to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent

Comment: p:confirmDialog is an implementation of UIPanel. http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/4.0/org/primefaces/component/confirmdialog/ConfirmDialog . f:ajax cant be nested in it.
Also see,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539992/fajax-unable-to-attach-fajax-to-non-clientbehaviorholder-parent

Answer (score 1):

What you want cannot be done, as in, it's not supported by JSF (not just primefaces).

The `<p:confirmDialog/>`is not a `ClientBehaviourHolder`(components that support listening for actions on the client side).  You should just disable the `X` close button, forcing the user to click on either the Yes or No buttons. To disable the X:

```
 <p:confirmDialog id="theDialog" closable="false"/>
```

Or you could spring for the `<p:dialog/>`, which provides support for [listeners](http://primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/dialogClose.jsf)

Further reading:

- [<f:ajax> Unable to attach <f:ajax> to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539992/fajax-unable-to-attach-fajax-to-non-clientbehaviorholder-parent/3540259#3540259)